# Creating an orphan mesh from nodal coordinates in abaqus using python

Tags: python, abaqus

I have a list of nodal coordinates taken from sections of a geometry created in catia. Using this geometries is it possible to create a orphan mesh using Python programming for Abaqus.

How could i connect these coordinates to form a mesh ? and how do i integrate it with Abaqus?

If anyone can share a small example or an idea would be really helpful for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a lot of nodes (> 100 at least) the best you can do is create a mesh outside Abaqus using a Python script. Based on my experience (half of my thesis was on this subject), I would recommend [Meshpy](http://documen.tician.de/meshpy/#) as the core library to your script. Also you should take a look at the INP files syntax (Abaqus input files), look inside [Abaqus Example Problems Manual](http://orange.engr.ucdavis.edu:2080/v6.10/books/exa/default.htm), there is plenty of examples.

In case you didn't know, all INP files contain an orphan mesh, native is only for meshes created inside Abaqus/CAE.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to create geometry in Abaqus/CAE and mesh the geometry.  This can be done using these steps:

1. Create a series of datum points in a part in Abaqus/CAE using something similar to the script below.
2. Join the datum points up with a series of wires using button 'Create wire: point to point'
3. Create faces by using the 'Cover Edges' button and selecting the wire edges.
4. Mesh the faces

Example code to create a series of datum points:

```
from part import *
modelName='Model-4'  #Enter model name.    
newPartName='Part-2' #Enter new part name   

currentModel=mdb.models[modelName]

datumList=((10.0, 0.0, 0.0),(1.0, 0.0, 0.0),(0.0, 0.0, 0.0),(0.0, 1.0, 0.0))

part=currentModel.Part(dimensionality=THREE_D, name=newPartName, type=DEFORMABLE_BODY)

for datumCoords in datumList:
    part.DatumPointByCoordinate(coords=datumCoords)
```